Deeper bevel (geometry nodes?)


Is it possible to achieve this effect (strong recess) using modifiers or geometry nodes? Unfortunately, the bevel does not help much, it cannot be forced to deepen. I tried using geometry nodes, but after a few hours of making and searching the web, I gave up.

Can't you simply select the centre loop of edges and scale it inwards?

depends a lot on how much you want to generalize this...
